# getting undefined reference to a function in commonLISP

Tags: list, loops, syntax, lisp

I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
    (defun nextStates (st)
  "generate all possible states"
  (setf N 0)
  (setf states-list (make-list 9))
  (setf list-actions (possible-actions))

  (loop for x in list-actions do

     (setf aux (nextState st x))
     (when (not(member aux (states-list) :test #'equalp))
         (progn
            (setf (nth N states-list) aux)
            (setf N (+ N 1))
         )
     )
  )

    (values states-list)
  )
```

nextState is a function and states-list is a list, both of which are defined. I'm getting "undefined reference to states-list". 
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you forgot `do`?

Comment: @Sylwester I tried to, but it didn't compile. How can I put multiple statements inside do?

Comment: It should take multiple forms Eg. `(loop :for var :in list :do expr1 expr2...)`. If you don't have a then clause you should `(when (not (member...) expr1 expr2...) `

Comment: @Sylwester So just adding `do` after `(loop for x in list-actions` should do the trick right? I tried to compile it that way and now I'm getting "Undefined function states-list. Why is is seeing states-list as a function?

Comment: Still missing `do`: `(loop for x in list-actions do (setf aux (nextState st x)) (when (not (member aux states-list :test #'equalp)) (setf (nth N states-list) aux) (setf N (+ N 1))))` but `N` and `aux` must exist though or you should add it as variables in the loop.

Comment: @Sylwester It's now working! Thank you very much. I thought do couldn't take multiple forms.

Comment: The error was probably because you had parentheses around `states-list`. I noticed you did `nth` on it and assumed you didn't have it as both a function and a variable. Parentheses cannot be used as in math as it means `apply` when not in a macro form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming the badly camel case to lisp case I'm left with this.

```
(defun next-states (st)
  "generate all possible states"
  (loop :for action :in (possible-actions)
        :for aux := (next-state st action) :then (next-state st action)
        :when (not (member aux states-list :test #'equalp))
          :collect aux :into states-list
        :finally (return states-list)))
```

As a test here is what I had:

```
(defun possible-actions ()
  "have duplicates to see not member in action"
  '(0 1 3 3 4))

(defun next-state (st action)
  "Simple version for test"
  (+ st action))

(next-states 3) ; ==> (3 4 6 7)
```